# Bonding and default gateway problem (CentOS)

Tags: linux, networking, centos, bonding

I configured network bonding on two machine with centos 5.5.
Bonding works well, but the problem is default gateway: it is not configured!

I follow [this](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BondingInterfaces) tutorial.
I added GATEWAY in both (and either) /etc/sysconfig/network and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0.
But, when I restart network (or server) there is no default gateway (route command).

This is `ip route ls` output after network restart:

> 10.0.0.0/16 dev bond0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.88

Where is my mistake?

```
/etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
IPV6INIT=no
HOSTNAME=mysql2
NOZEROCONF=yes
GATEWAY=10.0.1.10

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0 
DEVICE=bond0
IPADDR=10.0.0.88
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
NETWORK=10.0.0.0/16
BROADCAST=10.0.255.255
GATEWAY=10.0.1.10
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
USERCTL=no
TYPE=Ethernet

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
USERCTL=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
USERCTL=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NETWORK=10.0.0.0/16
```

I don't think this is specified correctly. It should be just

```
NETWORK=10.0.0.0
```

or try leaving it out entirely its redundant information

Answer (score 1):

TrevorH (a linux sysadmin) solved my problem (I post my question also into [centos forum](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=29636&start=0#forumpost123015)).

Removing NETWORK and BROADCAST lines from ifcfg-bond0, the default gateway is configured.

Answer (score 0):

The correct place for the default gateway is /etc/sysconfig/network - remove it from your bond scripts. Also ensure that your route defined as

GATEWAY=x.x.x.x

What does `ip route ls` show after `service network restart`

Comment: I didn't wrote, but I also tried to remove GATEWAY from bond script. Now, I add ip route output into my question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use booth like that, or you set network=10.0.0.0/16 without netmask or you set network=10.0.0.0 and netmask=255.255.0.0.

Regards.